# Can't install Windows Activation Process Service on Windows Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server

im struggling install a website on a given server from my client, which already has IIS but seem like it wasn't working well.

After a few attempts, I tried to reinstall the IIS, and from some article i heard that I must remove the Windows Activation Process Service.
Then, in a moment of stupidity I ran the command `sc delete service was` in Powershell. After that I realized I should user the Server manager to Uninstall/Install. So I tried to uninstall then install it again, and reset the server. But now Windows Activation Process Service doesnt appear in the Services list anymore (run --> services.msc).

Could you tell me how to install it properly now? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I remove the IIS and reinstall again, now it works. Thanks everyone.